# htaccess redirect if folder exists else redirect to another folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, web

I would like to redirect with htaccess to a certain folder 'setup' if it exists.

Else it must do the stock standard redirect as it was :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$ /site [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /api/index.php [L]
```

Now my htaccess-Fu are not nearly where it supposed to be. I read the posts I could find on SO but none of them helped for my specific case.

Then I have a sub-question: Is it bad practice to have this permanently in your htaccess file? Seeing as it would only exist the first time you setup  the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I often see people doing this via PHP, but doing it via htaccess does seem like a great alternative!

So what you're looking for is something like:

```
RewriteEngine on

# The part your looking for: If setup is present and you're not in it redirect there!
# If the setup directory exists in the document root...
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/setup -d 
# ...and you're not in setup..
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(setup) [NC] 
# ...redirect to setup - with a 302 (temporary redirect) to make sure the browser won't cache the redirect.
RewriteRule ^(.*) /setup [L,redirect=302]

# the rest of your htaccess should go here... for instance:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Tried it gets error : Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.

Tested it in a separate domain with just the htaccess and the setup folder with a index.php in it.

Comment: @Carlo-HeinVersfeld, I tested locally and it worked great! is your directory called "setup"? Are you running the test on the root of the domain?

Comment: Yes. Did it on a vagrant box. Might it be because it is running on a sub-domian ?

Think the redirect to setup fails - if I remove the #rest part I dont get the error in the logs - but still no redirect to the setup folder

Comment: @Carlo-HeinVersfeld, if it's in the root of a subdomain you shouldn't have any issue. Quick question, did you configured the subdomain on a sub-directory of the main site, that already has another .htaccess file in it? Because I can't really reproduce the problem! Can you send your entire .htaccess contents? Thanks

Comment: `<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName ebase.eldev.local
ServerAlias www.ebase.eldev.local
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
DocumentRoot /vagrant/webroot/ElianceBase2015
<Directory /vagrant/webroot/ElianceBase2015>
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
Allow from all
Options +Includes +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>`
with just 
/.htaccess
/setup/index.php

just that in there.

Comment: @Carlo-HeinVersfeld, for any change do you have an app running at "/vagrant/webroot/" and an .htaccess there? I know it would be strange but that may be affecting the subdomain. I'll try to reproduce your issue asap :) Thanks

Comment: got it working seems the comments made a difference: `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/setup -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(setup) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /setup [L,redirect=302]`

Comment: Sorry @Carlo-HeinVersfeld, I added those already in SO! Just updated my answer, from front to the top of the line they refer to! Cheers, glad I could help :)